# Marking one article as Featured to show on the Taxonomy Landing Page in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, custom-fields, drupal-theming

On my Taxonomy (Category) Landing Page, I am listing all the articles in the chronological format. But I also want to show one Article (that I select) or a latest one as a Featured Article on the Landing Page. With the Featured Article, I'd show the following Custom Fields within the Article:-

- Featured Image
- Title
- Couple of other custom fields

My question is how to do it with a probable customized loop or any module?

Comment: After Searching, I think I can use Views to accomplish it. Now I was wondering, even if I set up fields I need within a view, how would I set a view, so that it only shows the articles within a specific category?

Comment: Search Google for "Views filters" it is a low level views task. In the filters add a field of that Taxonomy (Landing Page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a view (block) and setup your fields.
- Add a Taxonomy Term ID Contextual Filter
- Choose "Provide Default Value" in the "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE" section
- Choose "Taxonomy term ID from URL" in type.
- Save the contextual filter and then save your view.
- Have the view block display on the taxonomy term pages.